# mysql import statement cuts off integers

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to import a text file into a mysql database. First I created the schema:

```
Create table tbl_windspeed(
    year int,
    month varchar(50),
    speed decimal,
    location varchar(50));
```

Here's a portion of the txt file:

```
2015    feb     15.7    Neumayer
2015    sep     \N      Neumayer
2015    nov     \N      Neumayer
2015    jun     17.3    Neumayer
1976    jul     \N      Rothera
1976    may     \N      Rothera
1976    oct     \N      Rothera
1976    apr     \N      Rothera
1976    mar     \N      Rothera
1976    aug     \N      Rothera
1976    jan     \N      Rothera
```

Here's the import statement and the same rows as above:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'csv_windspeed.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_windspeed;

|015 | feb   |    16 | Neumayer
|015 | sep   |  NULL | Neumayer
|015 | nov   |  NULL | Neumayer
|015 | jun   |    17 | Neumayer
 |76 | jul   |  NULL | Rothera
 |76 | may   |  NULL | Rothera
 |76 | oct   |  NULL | Rothera
 |76 | apr   |  NULL | Rothera
 |76 | mar   |  NULL | Rothera
 |76 | aug   |  NULL | Rothera
 |76 | jan   |  NULL | Rothera
```

So there's two things:

1) The year integers are getting cut off

2) They wind speed data isn't being read as a decimal even though it is specified as such in the table schema.

One thing that's interesting though, when I run the query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_windspeed WHERE year = 1962
```

I get this result:

```
  |62 | nov   |     8 | Faraday
  |62 | jun   |    11 | Faraday
|1962 | jul   |    11 | Grytviken
|1962 | may   |     7 | Grytviken
|1962 | oct   |     6 | Grytviken
|1962 | apr   |     7 | Grytviken
|1962 | mar   |    12 | Grytviken
|1962 | aug   |     7 | Grytviken
|1962 | jan   |     9 | Grytviken
|1962 | dec   |     8 | Grytviken
|1962 | feb   |     9 | Grytviken
|1962 | sep   |     9 | Grytviken
|1962 | nov   |    12 | Grytviken
|1962 | jun   |     9 | Grytviken
   |2 | jul   |    13 | Halley
   |2 | may   |     9 | Halley
   |2 | oct   |    11 | Halley
   |2 | apr   |    13 | Halley
   |2 | mar   |    11 | Halley
   |2 | aug   |    10 | Halley
   |2 | jan   |     8 | Halley
   |2 | dec   |     9 | Halley
   |2 | feb   |    11 | Halley
   |2 | sep   |    14 | Halley
   |2 | nov   |     9 | Halley
   |2 | jun   |    11 | Halley
    | | jul   |    14 | Signy
    | | may   |    11 | Signy
    | | oct   |    19 | Signy
    | | apr   |    15 | Signy
    | | mar   |    11 | Signy
    | | aug   |    12 | Signy
    | | jan   |    11 | Signy
    | | dec   |    11 | Signy
    | | feb   |    16 | Signy
    | | sep   |    18 | Signy
    | | nov   |    13 | Signy
    | | jun   |    16 | Signy
```

So even though mysql realizes these rows are from the year 1962, they are still getting cut off. Also again, the decimal is getting cut off. I'm not really sure what's going on here, any help would be appreciated, thank you.

UPDATE: When I run a query (getting the top 10 highest windspeeds) in mysql this is the result:

```
|1988 | jun   |  27.9 | Neumayer
|1997 | nov   |  26.9 | Neumayer
|1981 | jul   |  26.8 | Neumayer
|2002 | jun   |  25.8 | Neumayer
|2006 | aug   |  25.6 | Neumayer
|1989 | apr   |  25.5 | Neumayer
|1995 | aug   |  25.5 | Neumayer
|1981 | may   |  25.4 | Neumayer
|1999 | aug   |    25 | Neumayer
   |8 | sep   |    25 | Signy
```

Notice the last row's year column gets cut off. Now when I run a C program that runs that same exact query, this is the result:

```
988    jun    27.9    Neumayer
997    nov    26.9    Neumayer
981    jul    26.8    Neumayer
002    jun    25.8    Neumayer
006    aug    25.6    Neumayer
989    apr    25.5    Neumayer
995    aug    25.5    Neumayer
981    may    25.4    Neumayer
999    aug    25      Neumayer
958    sep    25      Signy
```

I think it must have something to do with a view setting? It's the same query, same data, but sometimes the year column gets cut off.

Comment: Actually `decimal` is getting rounded.  Can you change that field to `float`?  I'm still thinking.

Comment: Just changed the schema to float and it work. Not sure why, but you're 1/1 right now. Can you fix the year column?

Comment: Yeah, it's very strange. `INT` defaults to `INT(11)` but try giving it an explicit limit - `INT(5)`

Comment: Why 5 wouldn't it be 4?

Comment: I tried explicitly setting int to int(5) but nothing changed

Comment: I always like to have some for good measure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. My original .txt file was created in windows. I then imported it (through WinSCP) into my Linux machine. I found out that Linux does a weird thing with characters, and sometimes character conversions between Linux and Microsoft can be a little rough. So to test this theory out, I opened up a new vi in Linux and copy and pasted the data from the original .txt file. Then I loaded the data into my table using the new vi file. It worked, no errors.